# Merge 2 dictionaries and store them in pandas dataframe where one dictionary has variable length list elements

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I'm iterating through some HTML divs like this with Beautiful Soup:

```
for div in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'result'}):
            adLink = div.a.get('href') 
            adInfo= {
                              u'adLink':adLink,
                              u'adThumbImg':...some code...,
                              u'adCounty':...some code...

                             }
            adFullInfo = getFullAdInfo(adLink)
            adInfo.update(adFullInfo) 

ads_CarsURL = pd.DataFrame(data=adInfo) #Create pandas DF
```

Where `getFullAdInfo` is function

```
def getFullAdInfo  {
...some code...
}
```

which returns dictionary which looks something like this:

```
{'adID': '2027007',
 'adTitle': 'Ford 750 Special',
 'adDatePublished': '20.11.2009',
 'adTimePublished': '14:23',
 'adViewed': '102',
 'carPriceEUR': '600',
 'carManufacturer': 'Ford'}
```

So in each iteration I'm getting values from `adInfo` dict and from `adFullInfo` function which returns another dict and merging them so I can have single dictionary record. 
Idea is on the end to create pandas dataframe.

Error I get is:

> ```
> ValueError: arrays must all be same length
> ```

I don't know why is that so when I initially defined all variables for each dictionary key and assigned empty string to them like `adID=""` in case they are missing.

Comment: how are you combining them into 1 dataframe? If you just append a "temp dataframe" into your final dataframe, then you don't need to worry about the length, it'll just fill that with a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried various options, in this is what gave best results:

I've properly merged dictionaries with `adFull = {**adBasicInfo,**adOtherInfo}` and append them into `adFullList`  list in each iteration.

After that I could successfully create pandas dataframe from `adFullList` list.

Other solution didn't work because second dictionary had list type of element for some of the values. They look like this:

```
adFullDF.iloc[2]['carSafety']
```

which gives:

```
['Self-tightening belts', 'Rear seat belts', 'Active head restraints']
```

List of dictionaries in that case can solve shape problem which pandas will give in case you try to save dictionaries in pandas dataframe when one of the dictionaries has variable length list items for some of the items.

Names of some dictionaries are changed for better understanding:

```
adBasicInfo = {} # 1.st dictionary
adOtherInfo = {} # 2.nd dictionary
adFullInfo = {}  # Merged dictionary
adFullList = []  # List for appending merged dictionaries

# In each iteration merge dicts and append them in the list
 for div in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'result'}):
           ..some code...
            adBasicInfo = {
                              u'adLink':adLink,
                              u'adThumbImg':...some code...,
                              u'adCounty':...some code...

                             }
        adOtherInfo = getFullAdInfo(adLink)      # Get complex dict      
        adFull = {**adBasicInfo,**adOtherInfo} # Merge dicts
        adFullList.append(adFull)              # Append dicts to list

# Save final version of list as pandas dataframe
adFullDF = pd.DataFrame(data=adFullList) # Save final list to dataframe
```

Answer (score 3):

After you get the full ad, convert that to a 1 row dataframe, then just append that into a final dataframe. That will take care of the mismatch lengths and if there is data not available on an ad that is there for others. You'll have to work out the logic, as you haven't provided that part of your code to test. So quick example below of what I mean:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'adID': '2027007',
 'adTitle': 'Ford 750 Special',
 'adDatePublished': '20.11.2009',
 'adTimePublished': '14:23',
 'adViewed': '102',
 'carPriceEUR': '600',
 'carManufacturer': 'Ford'}

data2 = {'adID': '20555',
 'adTitle': 'Honda',
 'adTimePublished': '11:23',
 'adViewed': '2',
 'carManufacturer': 'Honda'}

# Initialize empty dataframe
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate through your dictionaries, convert to 1 row dataframe and append it to your final dataframe
for data in [data1, data2]:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])

    final_df = final_df.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Specifically with what you provided**, it will be something like:

```
ads_CarsURL = pd.DataFrame()    
for div in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'result'}):
            adLink = div.a.get('href') 
            adInfo= {
                              u'adLink':adLink,
                              u'adThumbImg':...some code...,
                              u'adCounty':...some code...

                             }
            adFullInfo = getFullAdInfo(adLink)
            adInfo.update(adFullInfo) 

            temp_df = pd.DataFrame(adInfo, index=[0])

            ads_CarsURL = final_df.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (final_df.to_string())
  adDatePublished     adID adTimePublished           adTitle adViewed carManufacturer carPriceEUR
0      20.11.2009  2027007           14:23  Ford 750 Special      102            Ford         600
1             NaN    20555           11:23             Honda        2           Honda         NaN
```

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4) into shape (1) - thats for temp_df = pd.DataFrame(adInfo, index=[0])

Comment: @Harvey do you still need help with that?

Comment: @Harvey, what version of pandas are you using?